# Adding Language to Cumulocity

Tags: localization, cumulocity

We want to add another language to the Cumulocity plattform. We received the *.po file for our UI Version from the support and generated a test translation to check how it works before ordering the translation. We got the info that we can just put the *.po file to an app or a widget and when deployed, the translation should be visible for the whole platform, but that does not seem to work, do we have to set a reference or something somewhere inside of the app or widget to the po file or is there another aspect we should take a look at?

Best Regards

Our Translationfile contains following header for now:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: \n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: \n"
"PO-Revision-Date: \n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"Language: zh_CN\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: .\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 2.2\n"

msgid "\"{{c8y_Dashboard.name}}\" - dashboard"
msgstr "\"{{c8y_Dashboard.name}}\"-往好处说是超脱豁达"

msgid "\"{{c8y_Kpi.label}}\" - data point"
msgstr "\"{{c8y_Kpi.label}}\"-北洋军阀从白走到黑"

[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the po file into a folder "locales" into your plugin and run the build. Here's an example that worked for me: https://bitbucket.org/m2m/cumulocity-ui-plugin-examples/src/bac470cb8149/plugins/weather

Comment: Hi André, I tried it with a Testfile we got from a translation office but still after deployment I can't choose the new language (chinese) in the dropdown menu of the user settings where you could set the language. Is there some specific meta information needed?

Comment: Are you trying to translate Cumulocity to Chinese or is it just for additional plugins developed by you? If it's for the first case, please have a chat with your Cumulocity contact because there are Chinese translations for both variants. I'll check with the guys if I missed something for the second part.

Comment: It's the first case, I will contact them and asked about that again. I think we already talked with them about that but they didn't mention anything. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok, let me know if you are stuck somewhere.